# Error: expected file.path to export a function or instance

Tags: babeljs, generategenerator, generate

I creating a generator plugin named `generate-swap-project` for the `generate` generator tool.

Let's first see:

> - https://github.com/generate: A new command line tool and developer framework for scaffolding out GitHub projects. A more powerful, composable, functional alternative to Yeoman.
> - https://github.com/generate/generate: A new command line tool and developer framework for scaffolding out GitHub projects. Generate offers the robustness and configurability of Yeoman, the expressiveness and simplicity of Slush, and more powerful flow control and composability than either.
> - https://github.com/rbecheras/generate-swap-project A generator for SWAP projects (the generator I'm working on)
> - https://github.com/rbecheras/generate-swap-project/tree/1-convert-to-standard-code-style: A generator for SWAP projects (the readme on master branch)
> - https://github.com/rbecheras/generate-swap-project/tree/1-convert-to-standard-code-style: (the readme on problematic branch)

The master branch works fine and tests pass on travis AND on local dev host.
Tests are run by the  following yarn script (on master):

```
$ yarn test
```

However in the [PR #2](https://github.com/rbecheras/generate-swap-project/pull/2) `Resolve #1 "Convert to ESNext/StandardJS code style"`, I made the following changes:

- converted `ES5` codebase to `ESNext`
- moved codebase to `src/lib` and `src/tests`
- added a `generator.js` file a t root level that just requires `./dist/lib/generator.js`
- added yarn scripts: clear + lint + build + test (cf. [Readme section about the build pipeline](https://github.com/rbecheras/generate-swap-project/tree/1-convert-to-standard-code-style#discover-the-tasks-pipeline))

> Ref. to the branch [1-convert-to-standard-code-style](https://github.com/rbecheras/generate-swap-project/tree/1-convert-to-standard-code-style)

Tests are run by the  following yarn script (on branch `1-convert-to-standard-code-style`):

```
$ yarn travis
```

or (its alias)

```
$ yarn pipeline
```

that is task sequence for `yarn clear && yarn lint && yarn build && yarn test`

But one test fails (1 test fails for 14 test pass) with a strange error: `Error: expected file.path to export a function or instance`:

```
$ yarn pipeline
yarn run v1.3.2
$ yarn clear && yarn lint && yarn build && yarn test
$ yarn rimraf build dist
$ /home/remi/d/dev/generate-swap-project/node_modules/.bin/rimraf build dist
$ yarn lint:esnext
$ yarn standard src/*.js src/**/*.js
$ /home/remi/d/dev/generate-swap-project/node_modules/.bin/standard 'src/*.js' src/lib/generator.js src/tests/plugin.js src/tests/test.js
$ yarn build:lib && yarn build:tests && yarn build:docs
$ yarn babel src/lib/ --out-dir dist/lib --source-maps
$ /home/remi/d/dev/generate-swap-project/node_modules/.bin/babel src/lib/ --out-dir dist/lib --source-maps
src/lib/generator.js -> dist/lib/generator.js
$ yarn babel src/tests/ --out-dir dist/tests --source-maps
$ /home/remi/d/dev/generate-swap-project/node_modules/.bin/babel src/tests/ --out-dir dist/tests --source-maps
src/tests/plugin.js -> dist/tests/plugin.js
src/tests/test.js -> dist/tests/test.js
$ echo WARNING: No documentation build available yet
WARNING: No documentation build available yet
$ yarn mocha dist/tests/**/*.js
$ /home/remi/d/dev/generate-swap-project/node_modules/.bin/mocha 'dist/tests/**/*.js'


  generate-swap-project
    plugin
      ✓ should add tasks to the instance (80ms)
      ✓ should only register the plugin once

  generate-swap-project
    tasks
      ✓ should extend tasks onto the instance
      ✓ should run the `default` task with .build (186ms)
      ✓ should run the `default` task with .generate
    swap-project (CLI)
X =>  1) should run the default task using the `generate-swap-project` name (global install)
      ✓ should run the default task using the `swap-project` generator alias (local generator.js)
    swap-project (API)
      ✓ should run the default task on the generator
      ✓ should run the `swap-project` task
      ✓ should run the `default` task when defined explicitly
    sub-generator
      ✓ should work as a sub-generator
      ✓ should run the `default` task by default
      ✓ should run the `generator:default` task when defined explicitly
      ✓ should run the `generator:swap-project` task
      ✓ should work with nested sub-generators
      ✓ should run tasks as a sub-generator


  15 passing (1s)
  1 failing

  1) generate-swap-project
      swap-project (CLI)
        should run the default task using the `generate-swap-project` name (global install):
    Error: expected file.path to export a function or instance
      at Env.get (node_modules/base-env/lib/file.js:256:11)
      at Env.invoke (node_modules/base-env/lib/env.js:117:19)
      at Generate.<anonymous> (node_modules/base-generators/lib/generator.js:62:30)
      at Generate.getGenerator (node_modules/base-generators/index.js:157:22)
      at Object.exports.process (node_modules/base-generators/lib/tasks.js:127:24)
      at node_modules/base-generators/lib/tasks.js:86:23
      at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
      at exports.parse (node_modules/base-generators/lib/tasks.js:85:15)
      at Generate.generate (node_modules/base-generators/index.js:490:21)
      at Generate.generate (node_modules/base-generators/index.js:463:23)
      at Context.<anonymous> (dist/tests/test.js:87:11)



error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Here is the travis config

```
{
  "sudo": false,
  "language": "node_js",
  "node_js": "lts/carbon",
  "script": [
    "npm link",
    "npm install --global generate .",
    "yarn travis"
  ],
  "group": "stable",
  "dist": "trusty",
  "os": "linux"
}
```

And here is:

- the [travis failling build](https://travis-ci.org/rbecheras/generate-swap-project/builds/322604429?utm_source=github_status&utm_medium=notification) for the PR #2
- and the [log for the job running on `Node LTS/Carbon (v8.y.z)`](https://travis-ci.org/rbecheras/generate-swap-project/jobs/322604432)

I can't understand why that test (the one that runs the generator in CLI mode) fails after ESNext convertion and babel transpilation.

What's wrong with my PR ?

Comment: Why is this tagged `babeljs`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth The question is tagged `babeljs` because the tests pass for the branch `master` but fails for the branch `1-convert-to-standard-code-style`. That last branch does not contain any implementation change but the codebase is converted from `ES5` to `ESNext`, then `Babel` is used to transpile `ESNext` to `NodeJS` compatible `JavaScript` as part of the build pipeline before running tests (`Mocha` runs as transpiled TDD codebase on transpiled lib codebase). So I guess the bug is related to Babel  behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**That bug is indeed related to the consequences of the babel transpilation.**

The file `generator.js` at the root level directory use `CommonJS` module loading, that's required by the direct call by the global `generate` binary.

Here is the code of `./generator.js`:

```
module.exports = require('./dist/lib/generator')
```

But:

- since the module `./dist/lib/generator.js` is the result of a babel transpilation of `./src/lib/generator.js`, that exports the generator as a default anonymous function,
- and since the module `./generator.js` is a `CJS` module and use `require()`

then the required module is not the exported generator function but an object which contains a property `default`; and the value of this property is the generator function.

Thus, the correct way to implement `./generator.js` is as following:

```
module.exports = require('./dist/lib/generator').default
```

That's all!

> Here is the [PR that fix the issue](https://github.com/rbecheras/generate-swap-project/pull/12), and here is [the passing travis build](https://travis-ci.org/rbecheras/generate-swap-project/jobs/322611764) for that PR.